# Configuring VLANs/IP network for security and performance

Tags: networking, dns, routing, subnet, vlan

My networking level of understanding is still beginner, so bear with me.

I have several Ubiquiti products - USG (router), USW (switch), and UAP-AC (wap) installed in my home. I want to create multiple networks (management, client, storage, VoIP, and guest).

I have two servers that will provide DHCP and DNS services.

I have written out the following:

```
VLAN  0 (10.0.0.0/24)  - unmanaged
VLAN 10 (10.0.10.0/24) - client
VLAN 20 (10.0.20.0/24) - guest
VLAN 30 (10.0.30.0/24) - storage
VLAN 40 (10.0.40.0/24) - management
VLAN 50 (10.0.50.0/24) - VoIP
```

VLAN 20 cannot communicate with any other VLAN.

VLAN 30 is for my iSCSI network from my storage arrays to a dedicated ethernet port on each server host. That way no client can see my storage array directly. They will access files through file sharing on the host which grabs data from the storage array.

Here are my questions:

Do I put my router on the unmanaged network? ie 10.0.0.1
What subnet does my router belong to? ie 255.255.255.0

What subnet(s) does each VLAN (10-50) use?

Each VLAN, except storage, needs Internet access to download updates/patches.
How do I ensure they can reach the Internet?

What IP/subnet does my DNS/DHCP servers belong to? 10.0.0.0/24 or 10.0.10.0/24?
The DHCP service will lease out addresses for VLAN 10 and VLAN 20.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I put my router on the unmanaged network? ie 10.0.0.1

AFAIK, using a dedicated "management" VLAN is a common security measure.

> What subnet does my router belong to? ie 255.255.255.0
>
> What subnet(s) does each VLAN (10-50) use?

…didn't you *just* write yourself that each VLAN has a `/24` subnet?

So VLAN 40 would use the `10.0.40.0/24` aka `10.0.40.0/255.255.255.0` subnet just like you wrote in the question, and so on.

> Each VLAN, except storage, needs Internet access to download updates/patches. How do I ensure they can reach the Internet?

The router needs to belong to all VLANs, and can route between WAN ⇆ each VLAN just like it would normally route between WAN ⇆ regular LAN. Basically it sees tagged VLANs as individual Ethernet interfaces.

> What IP/subnet does my DNS/DHCP servers belong to? 10.0.0.0/24 or 10.0.10.0/24? The DHCP service will lease out addresses for VLAN 10 and VLAN 20

Both. It needs to be a member of both VLANs.

Comment: So a guest on 10.0.20.0/24 cannot talk to 10.0.10.0/24?  Also, since my desktop will be on 10.0.10/0/24 - Do I just create a virtual interface and tag it with VLAN 40 so I can access the management network and client network?

Comment: @mavx71xx: They all communicate just like separate physical LANs would – by going through the router in between. The router's firewall decides which (V)LANs can communicate with which.